# how would it be a entity relationship model example being distributed databases

Tags: database, relational-database, distributed-system, distributed-database

I have tried looking for a entity relationship model using the schema of distributed database but I found diagrams as it:

[image]

or I found entity relationship models but they are not using the schema of distributed database like this...

[image]

I did next diagram but teacher said me it is not using the Distributed database schema. How can i convert it to istributed database schema??
 [image]

Comment: The entity-relationship model is a conceptual/logical model which does not address and is not influenced by physical distribution.

Comment: but any entity-relationship model could use distrituted database? or do they need a special structure?

Comment: The entity-relationship model deals with the interpretation and association of pieces of data.  Where that data is stored is not part of the model.  However, your 2nd and 3rd diagrams are not proper ER diagrams, they model tables which are physical structures and may be affected by physical distribution.  However, I'm not aware of a formalized distributed table diagram notation.

Comment: There are quite a few initiatives aimed at solving the DDBS model issue, but I don't think any are described very well at this point.  It would be interesting to use something like Visio (because you can define templates) to create  a [table] => {distribution model} linkage though.  Hmmm..... lol